# 短い回答が自動でコメントに変換されるのを防ぐには？

Tags: サポート, コメント, よくある質問の案, 回答の仕方

短い回答が自動でコメントに変換されてしまうことがあります。しかし、回答として意図した投稿がコメントになってしまうと困ります。

どのようにして、この自動変換を回避できますか？

[←よくある質問の目次に戻る](/q/1484)

Answer (score 4):

#### 最初はリンク無しで投稿する

「質問へのリンクを含む」ことがコメント化される条件の一つです。よって、まずリンク無しで投稿し、すぐに編集でリンクを追加する、という回避方法が有ります。

参考: [Meta Stack Exchangeの回答](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298385/)